# Basic AngularJs not able to route to different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Not new to programming.  But I'm new to angularjs.  So it's probably a daft question..

I've been following a tutorial...but for some reason the page routing doesn't work.

I have a nav bar on the top, home, about, contact etc.  Typical stuff.

I would like to be able to click on "about" and be routed to the about.html file on the same page.

Nothing appears!  The index.html is in a partials file.  Please note I'm a newbie to angular and I've followed the instructions.  My server works fine.  The Nav bar looks good but doesn't link properly.

This is the code for index.html.  Thanks

```
<!-- define angular app -->
<html ng-app="financeApp">
<head>
  <!-- SCROLLS -->
  <!-- load bootstrap and fontawesome via CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css"       />

  <!-- SPELLS -->

  <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>


</head>
```

```
 <!-- HEADER AND NAVBAR -->
    <header>

    <div class="wrap">
        <!-- logo -->
        <a href="#!"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" /></a>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"></a>
            </div>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
















<!-- define angular controller -->

<div class="main" ng-controller="mainController">








<!-- MAIN CONTENT AND INJECTED VIEWS -->
<div id="main">


    <div ng-view>        </div>

    <!-- angular templating -->
    <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the code for script.js

```
 // create the module and name it financeApp
    // also include ngRoute for all our routing needs
 var financeApp = angular.module('financeApp', ['ngRoute']);

 // configure our routes
 financeApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('#', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/index.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('#about', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/about.html',
            controller  : 'aboutController'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .when('#contact', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/contact.html',
            controller  : 'contactController'
        });
 });

 // create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
 financeApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    // create a message to display in our view
    $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
 });

 financeApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
 });

financeApp.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Contact us! JK. This is just a demo.';
});
```

Comment: Please add <ng-view></ng-view> to your index.html

Comment: It's already on.  But no effect?  Thanks

Comment: Where? I can't see it, and why you include ng-route.js twice?

Comment: Scroll down to the bottom of index.html.  And I'm just following what the tutorial says.

Comment: Ok, can you show console errors?

Comment: How do I view error messages? I'm SSHing to a Ubuntu server. All of my editing is done on pico on ssh

Comment: The error output in your chrome/firefox debugger console (F12)

Comment: SyntaxError: syntax error angular.min.js:1
TypeError: angular is undefined angular-route.js:24
GET http://advice.local/script.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 2ms]
TypeError: e is undefined angular-route.min.js:10
The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67019/discussion-between-ben-diamant-and-superunknown).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work for you.
You need to create partials/main.html

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html ng-app="financeApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
  </head>

  <!-- HEADER AND NAVBAR -->
  <header>
    <div class="wrap">
      <!-- logo -->

      <!-- <a href="#!"><img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" /></a> -->

      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/"></a>
            </div>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <body>
    <div class="main" ng-controller="mainController">
      <!-- MAIN CONTENT AND INJECTED VIEWS -->
      <div id="main">
          <div ng-view></div>
          <!-- angular templating -->
          <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- App JS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**SCRIPT.JS**

```
  var financeApp = angular.module('financeApp', ['ngRoute']);

 // configure our routes
 financeApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/main.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/about.html',
            controller  : 'aboutController'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/contact.html',
            controller  : 'contactController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
      })
 });

 // create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
 financeApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    // create a message to display in our view
    $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
 });

 financeApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
 });

financeApp.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Contact us! JK. This is just a demo.';
});
```

Comment: Strangely enough...doesn't seem to work anymore.  The links are now  unclickable.

Comment: Strangely enough...doesn't seem to work anymore.  The links are now  unclickable and the page keeps crashing.

Really odd as your suggestion worked to begin with!

Comment: code updated. dont forget to add new partial _main.html_

Comment: Thanks, But I have.  I'm afraid the page just still crashes and the  links aren't clickable.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you followed [this](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating) tutorial and at least it explains everything what you need.

Possible errors could be:

1. Wrong folder name -> check again if the templateURLs match your file system
2. Errors in the template files

If you provide us some error messages from the console, we can help you better.

Comment: Hi THank you very much.  How do I view error messages?  I'm SSHing to a Ubuntu server.  All of my editing is done on pico on ssh.

Comment: I don't know which browser you're using. Go to your page and if you're using Firefox press CMD+ALT+K and if you're using chrome it depends on your OS. On Windows press CTRL+SHIFT+J and on MAC CMD+ALT+J. The web console displays different things like log messages and errors. This [FF Wiki Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) explains it in more detail.

Comment: Here's the errors.   SyntaxError: syntax error angular.min.js:1
TypeError: angular is undefined angular-route.js:24
GET http://advice.local/script.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 2ms]
TypeError: e is undefined angular-route.min.js:10
The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

Comment: ...do you have angular or angular-route js modules in the js folder? Try adding a dump of your file/folder structure into the question

Comment: It seems like you are not including angular.js before angular-route.js. Do you have this three lines in the head of your index.html?
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>`